# Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ScriptAssemblyAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

Hi I have a MVC ASP web app in C# on dot net 4.5 that was working fine until I added reference to Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb nuget package to use Azure B2C sign-in and sign-up, that's when I got the following error whenever I try to run the web app:

```
Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ScriptAssemblyAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

I haven't yet called any new functions, I just added the nuget package and it crashed like that. I am using visual studio 2015 on Windows 10 and the project is dot net framework 4.5.

Any help is really appreciated as I have been struggling for a few days on this and I'm not sure where to start to fix this issue.

Here is a list of all other nuget packages added to my project with their version number:

```
Antlr                   v3.5.0.2        
AutoMapper              v4.2.1          
bootstrap               v3.3.7          
bootstrap.v3.datetimepicker.css     v4.15.35        
buildwebcompiler            v1.11.323       
jquery                  v3.1.0          
jquery.validation           v1.15.1         
microsoft.aspnet.mvc            v5.2.3          
microsoft.aspnet.razor          v3.2.3          
microsoft.aspnet.web.optimization   v1.1.3          
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi         v5.2.3          
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client      v5.2.3          
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core        v5.2.3          
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost     v5.2.3          
Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages       v3.2.3          
microsoft.csharp            v4.0.1          
Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation v3.2.3      
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure        v1.0.0          
Modernizr               v2.8.3          
moment.js               v2.15.1         
Newtonsoft.Json             v9.0.1          
respond                 v1.4.2          
SharpShooter.Reports.Web.ASP.NET.Web    v2.1.1          
UnofficialAzure.StorageClient       v1.0.0
webgrease               v1.6.0          
windowsbase             v4.6.1055
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
[TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ScriptAssemblyAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.]
   System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
   System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext) +152
   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments) +158
   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg) +91
   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent) +438
   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, RuntimeType caType) +103
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(Boolean inherit) +37
   Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.SearchForStartupAttribute(String friendlyName, IList`1 errors, Boolean& conflict) +106
   Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.GetDefaultConfiguration(String friendlyName, IList`1 errors) +46
   Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.LoadImplementation(String startupName, IList`1 errorDetails) +75
   Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.Load(String startupName, IList`1 errorDetails) +21
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinBuilder.GetAppStartup() +115
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.InitializeBlueprint() +28
   System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore(T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory) +115
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context) +106
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +534
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +339
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ScriptAssemblyAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9922840
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +90
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +261
```

Please let me know if you want me to provide any other information.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you added the Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb nuget package , then it shows the error? Do you have any other operation to your project? I have created a test demo on my computer. After I installed the package, it works well.

Comment: @BrandoZhang-MSFT thanks for getting back to me. Yes I had this web app project for a couple of years and now I'm trying to add Azure AD to it so I added this nuget package and without modifying any code yet, I get this error when I run the web app. Did you add all the packages I listed then added the Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb and it still works for you? Thanks

Comment: Does this project created by .net 4.0? Then you change the property to the .net 4.5.

Comment: @BrandoZhang-MSFT  
No I think it was always 4.5. Does it make a difference? Thanks

Comment: Based on your error message I guess the reason may be about the project .net version. Besides I have created a test demo on my computer, but I installed SharpShooter.Reports.Web.ASP.NET.Web package,then my project show many errors, it seems need download the third part platform. I couldn't reproduce the error. Could you please share a test demo with github or onenote which exclude the SharpShooter package to me to reproduce the error. It will be easily for me to find the solution.

Comment: Hi @BrandoZhang-MSFT Thanks for your input. I managed to get around this problem by creating a new web app project from scratch and copying all the files from my existing one. Somehow this managed to make it work. I am having another issue which I posted to SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44133401/azure-b2c-getowincontext-authentication-challenge-creates-wrong-url-with-quest I would really appreciate it if you can assist me with it. Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind I managed to resolve this by updating the nuget packages