# Microsoft flow and B2C not working together

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, power-automate

I am using B2C tokens in a web api. The web api will be called from flow. The authorize url in flow is 
https://login.microsoftonline.com/lingeshtest.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=b2c_1_demo2

When flow redirects to the authorize end point it adds an additional question mark to the end of the url before appending the client id.
https://login.microsoftonline.com/lingeshtest.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_demo2?client_id=foobar...

whereas it should only append a & before adding client id.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd recommend that you add screenshots / more details of how you're setting up the Microsoft Flow + Azure AD B2C integration.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error before, I think tyou are using an old library , i think i updated to the latest MSAL pre release and it fixed

Looks like a duplicate of

[Azure B2C GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge creates wrong url with Question mark instead of And sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44133401/azure-b2c-getowincontext-authentication-challenge-creates-wrong-url-with-quest)